# Returning a value of a high order function doesn't

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
def retSomething(x: Int): Int => Int = x*x

assert(retSomething(5)(5) == 25)
assert(retSomething(1)(1) == 1)
assert(retSomething(1)(0) == 0)
```

But the assertions fail. Surely that is correct, but it says implementation is missing when running it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the implementation you are looking for is:

```
def retSomething(x: Int): Int => Int = y => x * y
```

What does the method `retSomething` mean? It takes an `Int` and returns a function `Int => Int`.
The function `Int => Int` takes another `Int` and returns an `Int`.

So we want to return with a function that takes a **new** `Int`, that's why we need: `y => x * y`.

Type inference works nicely here, you don't need to write (but can): `(y: Int) => x * y`

Answer (score 0):

this returns Int while expecting Int => Int

```
def retSomething(x: Int): Int => Int = x*x
```

it should be

```
def retSomething(x: Int): Int => Int = x => x*x
```